# pkginfo on SunOS reliable?

Tags: python, sunos

I am trying to understand why pkginfo lists newer versions of python on one of our SunOS servers.

> veeCan@JuneQA:~> python -V
>   Python 2.3.3

Output from pkginfo:

> veeCan@JuneQA:~> pkginfo -l | grep -i python
>
> > NAME:  Python 2.4.3
> >     PKGINST:  SMCpython
> >     NAME:  Python 2.4.3
> >     PKGINST:  SMCpython
> >     NAME:  python
> >     VENDOR:  The Python Group
> >     PKGINST:  SUNWPython
> >     NAME:  The Python interpreter, libraries and utilities
> >     DESC:  The Python interpreter, libraries and utilities
> >     PKGINST:  SUNWPython-devel
> >     NAME:  The Python interpreter, libraries and utilities - develper files - platform dependent, /usr filesystem
> >     DESC:  The Python interpreter, libraries and utilities - develper files - platform dependent, /usr filesystem
> >     PKGINST:  SUNWPython-share
> >     NAME:  The Python interperer, libraries and utilities - platform independent files, /usr/sfw/share
> >     DESC:  The Python interperer, libraries and utilities - platform independent files, /usr/sfw/share
> >     PKGINST:  SUNWlxml-python
> >     NAME:  The XML library - Python bindings
> >     DESC:  The XML library - Python bindings
> >     PKGINST:  SUNWlxsl-python
> >     NAME:  The XSLT library - Python bindings
> >     DESC:  The XSLT library - Python bindings
> >     NAME:  PostgreSQL 8.2 additional Perl, Python & TCL server procedural languages
> >     DESC:  PostgreSQL 8.2.9 additional Perl, Python & TCL server procedural languages
> >     NAME:  PostgreSQL additional Perl, Python & TCL server procedural languages
> >     DESC:  PostgreSQL 8.3.3 additional Perl, Python & TCL server procedural languages
> >     NAME:  cx_Oracle python module
> >     PKGINST:  ipython
> >     NAME:  iPython 0.9.1
> >     NAME:  Psyco Python
> >     NAME:  Python MySQL Library for Python 2.6
> >     PKGINST:  python26
> >     NAME:  Python 2.6.1 and other useful modules.
> >     NAME:  Python xlrd (read excel) 0.7.1
> >     NAME:  Setuptools for Python 0.6c9
> >     NAME:  Twill for Python 0.9

I show that python is installed here:

> veeCan@JuneQA:~> which python 
>   /usr/sfw/bin/python

pointing to python2.3. So this is the python home dir, which must be setup as an env var, I get that part - however, why/how does pkginfo show newer versions? Is pkginfo reliable? Is there a similar/better command to find versions of installed software?

If I can be pointed to any link/documentation, that will do as well!

Thanks in advance,
veeCan

Comment: Is it possible you've also got 2.4 install? Does `which python2.4` return anything?

Comment: ah, yes - veeCan@JuneQA:/usr/sfw/bin> which python2.4                                                                                          0
/usr/local/bin/python2.4

Comment: I guess then, pkginfo lists the highest versions of installed s/w even though it may not be the default version.

Comment: `pkginfo` is a pretty old tool (which, given the age of the system you are on is probably appropriate).  As far as I can remember, it just looks for some data files in a directory (maybe `/var/spool/pkg`?) and whatever it finds there is going to be what it reports.  Depending on how things were installed, one installation may not have included an info file or one may have overwritten another... just my best guess.

Comment: Thanks FatalError, appreciate your input!